# Ctrl + Alt + Del and F keys Using Telnet

Tags: rhel, telnet, serial-console

I only have serial access to a server, and I am trying to access its BIOS using telnet (it's not a direct serial, but a remote serial connection).

My telnet certainly reaches the server, as I can see it's failed boot, but I want to restart it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, however this is captured by my local machine. F-keys also seem to be captured by my local machine.

For the RHEL telnet application, what is the default method for issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>?

For the RHEL telnet application, what is the default method for issuing F keys?

Comment: Try `<ESC>R<ESC>r<ESC>R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most bios accept various versions of the vt100 keyboard escape sequences for function keys. For example, the [dell console redirection guide](http://www.noesisinc.com/links/DellDocs/PowerEdge2650/UserGuide/5g387ad0.htm) lists amongst others the equivalents:

```
F7     <Esc> <Shift>ov  or   <Esc> [ 1 8 ~
```

and also some extra non-standard sequences like

```
<Ctrl><Alt><Del>   <Esc> <Shift>r <Esc> r <Esc> <Shift> r
```

(For `<Shift>ov` you would type `OV` of course).  Unfortunately, these key sequences often have to be typed very rapidly, as only a small timeout is usually allowed between characters.

One way of sending such a sequence through telnet is to get your terminal emulator to generate the string upon some binding.  This is very terminal emulator dependant.

Another is to disconnect your telnet and run a command to send just the sequence through a new telnet connection. For example, for testing, this expect script does a login and sends the F7 sequence (`\033\[18~`).

```
#!/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet localhost
expect login:
send myuserid\r
expect Password: 
send mypassword\r
expect "\$ "
send "echo hi\r"
expect "hi"
expect "\$ "
send "dd count=6 bs=1 | od -c\r"
send "\033\[18~\r"
expect "\$"
send "echo hi\r"
expect "hi"
send_user "done\n"
```

Obviously, you won't need to login to your bios, so you might just have

```
#!/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet remotebios
expect "Connected to "
send "\033\[18~"
```

You can also try more simply

```
echo -e '\033[18~' | nc remotebios 23
```